# How do I change the owner of an event trigger in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altereventtrigger.html) states that the command for altering the owner of an event trigger is:

`ALTER EVENT TRIGGER name OWNER TO { new_owner | CURRENT_USER | SESSION_USER }`

But it errors with:

`[42704] ERROR: event trigger "insert_component_relationship" does not exist`

I thought that meant I needed to qualify it with the schema name so I tried:

`ALTER EVENT TRIGGER schema.name OWNER TO { new_owner }`

but that screamed at me as well with:

`[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "."`

Then I just started trying other combinations of commands I thought would work, ex:

`ALTER TRIGGER name ON table OWNER TO { new_owner }`

`ALTER TRIGGER name ON schema.table OWNER TO { new_owner }`

To no avail. Under the `name` parameter on this [page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtrigger.html) seems to suggest that the schema is inferred when it's created but makes no mention of schema qualifying when trying to alter the trigger.

EDIT Actual command run with pseudo values:

`ALTER EVENT TRIGGER modify_relationship OWNER TO new_admin_user;`

`ALTER EVENT TRIGGER products.modify_relationship OWNER TO new_admin_user;`

Comment: 1. Is your trigger actually an `event` trigger? 2. Can you put the actual command you're running, maybe with pseudo names, but without stuff like `{ }` so we can see if there's a syntax error?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure now. It actually doesn't seem that way. It doesn't show up with the `\dy` meta command. Do regular triggers have a concept of ownership?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Had a look at the documentation and couldn't see anything about ownership for regular triggers.

Comment: If you formulate what we just resolved into an answer I can accept that. Maybe put something along the lines "Make sure the trigger is an actual event trigger, check with the meta-command `\dy`. Normal triggers do not have a concept of ownership"

Comment: Thanks but since I don't know for certain I won't post it as an answer - however you can always post it yourself and accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively minor mistake.

Make sure the trigger is an actual event trigger.

Check with the meta-command `\dy`. If it doesn't show up here, it's probably not an event trigger.

[`The CREATE TRIGGER statement in PostgreSQL implements a subset of the SQL standard. The following functionalities are currently missing:`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html#SQL-CREATETRIGGER-COMPATIBILITY)

Triggers are defined by the SQL standard and there is no mention of ownership on the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html#SQL-CREATETRIGGER-COMPATIBILITY) for them

Altering the ownership of an event trigger is given as a option in the docs for [ALTER EVENT TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altereventtrigger.html)

[`There is no CREATE EVENT TRIGGER statement in the SQL standard.`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html#SQL-CREATEEVENTTRIGGER-COMPATIBILITY)

Thanks to [@eurotrash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3733070/eurotrash) for the comment that led me to the distinction.